# Split a stream if it contains multiple comma-separated values

Tags: java, lambda, filter, java-8, java-stream

This code will add all elements from mylist to mylist2.

How can I change it to add elements if it finds a comma, and separates them?

```
ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
mylist.add("test");
mylist.add("test2, test3");
ArrayList<String> mylist2 = new ArrayList<String>();

mylist.stream()
    .forEach(s -> mylist2.add(s));

mylist2.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

So, current output is:

```
test
test2, test3
```

and I need the second arraylist to contain and then print:

```
test
test2
test3
```

I know in Java 8 there are filters. Could I do something like

`.filter(p -> p.contains(",")...`
then something to split it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `split` each string and `flatMap` the resulting array:

```
mylist.stream()
      .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x.split(", ")))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do a `flatMap` including a `Pattern::splitAsStream` like

```
Pattern splitAtComma = Pattern.compile("\\s*,\\s*");
List<String> myList2 = mylist.stream().flatMap(splitAtComma::splitAsStream)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
mylist.forEach(str -> mylist2.addAll(Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s*,\\s*"))));
```

**Output**

```
test
test2
test3
```

Answer (score 1):

> and I need the second arraylist to contain and then print:

You could create two streams : one for creating the target List and another one for displaying it.

```
List<String> list2 = mylist.stream()
    .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x.split(", ")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

list2.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

or with one stream by using `peak()` to output the element of the Stream before collecting into a `List` :

```
List<String> list2 = mylist.stream()
    .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x.split(", ")))
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```